# Composite Unique Validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How I can use composite unique validation for two columns.
Like I have tow columns clinicName and datefield.
Example.
Hclinic, 07-2019
Hclinic, 08-2019

```
$this->validate($request, [
'clinicName'=> 'unique:hospital',
'dates'=> 'unique:hospital',
]);
```

My aim is to use Composite Unique Validation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) you can do it by defining the rule this way:

> **Adding Additional Where Clauses:**
>
> You may also specify additional query constraints by customizing the
>   query using the where method. For example, let's add a constraint that
>   verifies the account_id is 1:
>
> ```
> 'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
>     return $query->where('account_id', 1); 
> })
> ```

So you can change your code to:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'clinicName' => Rule::unique('hospital')->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('dates', Request::get('dates'));
]);
```

This will check uniqueness of your `clinicName` where `dates` is equal to the given `dates` of your request.

Comment: I do the same but some error occurred call undefined function Rule::unique()

Comment: What Laravel version do you use? Are you importing the Rule class?

Comment: Laravel 5.7..... yes i have import that class.. php artisan make:Rule Rule.... but I don't know what to do after that